# "who am I" after "sudo su -i" always displays the real user's login datetime in ksh

Tags: unix, datetime, ksh, sudo, su

I need to record the real user and the real time into the history list. For that I use `trap 'who am i|read -s' debug`, but it does not record the real time. Here are the steps so you can verify this.

1. Login to my personal account on LINUX, say as byksk0, at  2015-10-08 10:38;
2. Run `sudo su - wsadmin`
3. Run `who am i`, it returns:

   ```
   byksk0   pts/0        2015-10-08 10:38 (255.255.255.0)
   ```
4. Rerun `who am i`, it ALWAYS returns:

   ```
   byksk0   pts/0        2015-10-08 10:38 (255.255.255.0)
   ```

   regardless how long this is run after the `sudo su -` command.

Is it possible to get the real time when a command is executed under wsadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "who" command returns the login time, not the time of execution of a last command or anything like it.
To get a timestamp: use the "date" command.

EDIT:

If you want that on one line:

`who am i | awk  '{printf "%s ", $1}' && date`

EDIT:

To try to anticipate the next question:
Date also supports formatting of the date and time it outputs e.g:

`$ who am i | awk  '{printf "%s ", $1}' && date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
swa66 2015-10-08 21:20:34`

Comment: thank you for you answer. Can I make the real user name and real datetime displayed in one line? I run e.g who|awk '{print $1}' && date, it returns byksk0 at the 1st line, and the date time in the second line

Comment: Just don't output the newline in the awk command ... Added how to do that in the answer.